# How to add status to the table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following table where is clipping from my db. I have 2 types of contracts.

I: client pays for first 6mth 60$, next 6mth 120$ (111 client)

II: client pays for first 6mth 60$ but if want still pays 60$ the contract will be extended at 6mth, whole contract is 18mth. (321 client who still pays)

```
ID_Client | Amount | Amount_charge | Lenght | Date_from   | Date_to    | Reverse
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
111         60         60            12       2015-01-01   2015-01-31   12
111         60         60            12       2015-02-01   2015-02-28   11
111         60         60            12       2015-03-01   2015-03-31   10
111         60         60            12       2015-04-01   2015-04-30   9
111         60         60            12       2015-05-01   2015-05-31   8
111         60         60            12       2015-06-01   2015-06-30   7
111         120        60            12       2015-07-01   2015-07-31   6
111         120        60            12       2015-08-01   2015-08-31   5
111         120        60            12       2015-09-01   2015-09-30   4
111         120        60            12       2015-10-01   2015-10-31   3
111         120        60            12       2015-11-01   2015-11-30   2
111         120        60            12       2015-12-01   2015-12-31   1
111         120        60            12       2016-01-01   2015-01-31   0
111         120        60            12       2016-02-01   2015-02-29   0
321         60         60            12       2015-01-01   2015-01-31   12
321         60         60            12       2015-02-01   2015-02-28   11
321         60         60            12       2015-03-01   2015-03-31   10
321         60         60            12       2015-04-01   2015-04-30   9
321         60         60            12       2015-05-01   2015-05-31   8
321         60         60            12       2015-06-01   2015-06-30   7
321         60         60            12       2015-07-01   2015-07-31   6
321         60         60            12       2015-08-01   2015-08-31   5
321         60         60            12       2015-09-01   2015-09-30   4
321         60         60            12       2015-10-01   2015-10-31   3
321         60         60            12       2015-11-01   2015-11-30   2
321         60         60            12       2015-12-01   2015-12-31   1
321         60         60            12       2016-01-01   2016-01-30   0
321         60         60            12       2016-02-01   2016-02-31   0
321         60         60            12       2016-03-01   2016-03-30   0
321         60         60            12       2016-04-01   2016-04-31   0
```

I need to add status column.

A - normal period of agreement

D - where the agreement is doubled after 6mth but after 12mth is E(nd of agreemnt)

E - where contract is finished

L - where contract after 6mth was extended, after 18mth the status will be type E

For 321 Client after 12mth the lenght of contract was updated from 12 to 18

I have a lot of clients so i think better will be using loop to go by all clients?

```
 ID_Client | Amount | Amount_charge | Lenght | Date_from   | Date_to    | Reverse | Status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
111         60         60            12       2015-01-01   2015-01-31   12          A
111         60         60            12       2015-02-01   2015-02-28   11          A 
111         60         60            12       2015-03-01   2015-03-31   10          A
111         60         60            12       2015-04-01   2015-04-30   9           A
111         60         60            12       2015-05-01   2015-05-31   8           A
111         60         60            12       2015-06-01   2015-06-30   7           A
111         120        60            12       2015-07-01   2015-07-31   6           D
111         120        60            12       2015-08-01   2015-08-31   5           D
111         120        60            12       2015-09-01   2015-09-30   4           D
111         120        60            12       2015-10-01   2015-10-31   3           D
111         120        60            12       2015-11-01   2015-11-30   2           D
111         120        60            12       2015-12-01   2015-12-31   1           D
111         120        60            12       2016-01-01   2015-01-31   0           E
111         120        60            12       2016-02-01   2015-02-29   0           E
321         60         60            12       2015-01-01   2015-01-31   12          A
321         60         60            12       2015-02-01   2015-02-28   11          A
321         60         60            12       2015-03-01   2015-03-31   10          A
321         60         60            12       2015-04-01   2015-04-30   9           A
321         60         60            12       2015-05-01   2015-05-31   8           A
321         60         60            12       2015-06-01   2015-06-30   7           A
321         60         60            12       2015-07-01   2015-07-31   6           L
321         60         60            12       2015-08-01   2015-08-31   5           L
321         60         60            12       2015-09-01   2015-09-30   4           L
321         60         60            12       2015-10-01   2015-10-31   3           L
321         60         60            12       2015-11-01   2015-11-30   2           L
321         60         60            12       2015-12-01   2015-12-31   1           L
321         60         60            18       2016-01-01   2016-01-30   0           L
321         60         60            18       2016-02-01   2016-02-31   0           L
321         60         60            18       2016-03-01   2016-03-30   0           L
321         60         60            18       2016-04-01   2016-04-31   0           L
```

Comment: What is Reverse. Does Reverse always start with 12 and cannot be < 0? Are only  $60 and $120 ore there are others $ too?

Comment: @Mottor: Reverse depends from Lenght column. Reverse counting starts from the first value of Lenght. Do you know how to distinguish client which have or not doubled amount after e.g 6mth? The amounts may be various e.g. 20$, 30$, 50$ and so on.

Comment: Did you see the answer. If you do not  want to compare the sums you can use the analytic function ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...

Answer (score 0):

If the Reverse column is what I think:

```
update table1 a
set "Status"=
  CASE
      WHEN A."Reverse" > 6 THEN
         'A'
      WHEN A."Reverse" > 0 THEN
         DECODE (A."Amount", A."Amount_charge", 'L', 'D')
      ELSE
         CASE
            WHEN A."Amount" <> A."Amount_charge" THEN
               'E'
            ELSE
               CASE WHEN ADD_MONTHS ( (SELECT b."Date_from" FROM table1 b WHERE a."ID_Client" = b."ID_Client" AND b."Reverse" = 1),6) > a."Date_from" THEN 'L'
                  ELSE
                     'E'
               END
         END
   END
```

Better is to calculate the sums. The amount per month come from first payment. Something like this:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c2
   IS
          SELECT ID_CLIENT, --AMOUNT, AMOUNT_CHARGE, LENGTH, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO, REVERSE, STATUS, 
                 FIRST_VALUE (amount_charge) OVER (PARTITION BY id_client ORDER BY date_from) first_amount_charge,
                 SUM (amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id_client ORDER BY date_from) sum_amount,
                 SUM (amount_charge) OVER (PARTITION BY id_client ORDER BY date_from) sum_amount_charge
            FROM TABLE2
      FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
BEGIN
   FOR c1 IN c2
   LOOP
      UPDATE table2
         SET status = CASE WHEN c1.sum_amount <= 6 * c1.first_amount_charge THEN 'A' 
                           WHEN c1.sum_amount > 18 * c1.first_amount_charge THEN 'E' 
                           WHEN c1.sum_amount > c1.sum_amount_charge THEN 'D' 
                           ELSE 'L' 
                      END
       WHERE CURRENT OF c2;
   END LOOP;
END;
```